# Conditional resource compilation in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Can someone tell me if he tried this and worked?

I am trying to make conditional compilation through the visual studio editor! There is a property called "condition"
Every time I add a condition my resource file gets corrupted. I can compile it just fine, but If i try to open it with visual studio resource editor i get a "RC2135: file not found" for all my resources.

steps to reproduce the problem:

1. new c++ project win32
2. add resource
3. add a couple of images
4. rightclick resource.rc->Resource symbols (and add a flag like USE_IMAGES)
5. Compile (everything is ok)
6. rightclick a resource image, goto properties and in 'condition' add USE_IMAGES
7. do the same for the other image
8. compile ? (should be ok)
9. close resource editor. Try to edit resource file with editor and BAM. RC2135 file not found.

Am i missing something!?

Comment: How is it "unclear what [Ray] is asking"? You crazy people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a known bug that has been around for a decade!
way to go microsoft!